# Java Spring ошибка при выполнении теста SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, тестирование

Хочу протестировать внедрение зависимостей при помощи спринга в проекте из нескольких классов:

```
package soundsystem;

public interface CompactDisc {
    void play();
}
```

Реализация интерфейса:

```
package soundsystem;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisc {

    private String title = "Sgt. Peppers Lonely Hearts Club band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";

    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    }
}
```

Конфигурация:

```
package soundsystem;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

Тест:

```
package soundsystem;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }
}
```

При выполнении теста получаю ошибку:

```
15:16:23.350 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class soundsystem.CDPlayerTest].
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;

    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:171)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:621)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Что в этом коде не так и почему ничего не работает?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>



    <pluginRepositories>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>

        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]

    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createBootstrapContext(BootstrapUtils.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]: Unresolvable class definition; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.KotlinDetector.isKotlinReflectPresent()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(Ljava/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAttributes;

Этот метод был введен в версии 4.0.3 и поэтому вам надо обновить версию spring-core.

Comment: Это объяснение не помогло. Я обновил спринг до последней версии, но ошибки все равно остались. Что не так? Добавил в пост pom-файл.

Comment: Попробуйте [патч](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/KotlinDetector.java).